# Check which tag is most relevant with title

Tags: php, mysql

There are two dbs:

```
+-----+----------------+
| id  |     tag        |
+----------------------+
|  1  |      Audi      |
|  2  |      BMW       |
|  3  |  Volkswagen    |
|  4  |  Mercedes Benz |
+----------------------+
```

and

```
+-----+-------------------------------+------+
| id  |           title               |  tag |
+-------------------------------------+ -----+
|  1  |      Audi is a great car      | NULL | 
+-------------------------------------+------+
```

What I need to do:

1.Check which tag is most relevant with title.

2.Extract most relevant tag and insert into database near title.

What I did so far:

```
function compareStrings($s1, $s2) {
    //one is empty, so no result
    if (strlen($s1)==0 || strlen($s2)==0) {
        return 0;
    }

    //replace none alphanumeric charactors
    //i left - in case its used to combine words
    $s1clean = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9-]/", ' ', $s1);
    $s2clean = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9-]/", ' ', $s2);

    //remove double spaces
    while (strpos($s1clean, "  ")!==false) {
        $s1clean = str_replace("  ", " ", $s1clean);
    }
    while (strpos($s2clean, "  ")!==false) {
        $s2clean = str_replace("  ", " ", $s2clean);
    }

    //create arrays
    $ar1 = explode(" ",$s1clean);
    $ar2 = explode(" ",$s2clean);
    $l1 = count($ar1);
    $l2 = count($ar2);

    //flip the arrays if needed so ar1 is always largest.
    if ($l2>$l1) {
        $t = $ar2;
        $ar2 = $ar1;
        $ar1 = $t;
    }

    //flip array 2, to make the words the keys
    $ar2 = array_flip($ar2);


    $maxwords = max($l1, $l2);
    $matches = 0;

    //find matching words
    foreach($ar1 as $word) {
        if (array_key_exists($word, $ar2))
            $matches++;
    }

    return ($matches / $maxwords) * 100;    
}


$all_values = '';

$sql_object = "SELECT * FROM tag";
$result_object = mysql_query($sql_object);
while($row_object = mysql_fetch_array($result_object))
{
    $tag = $row_object['tag'];

    $sql_subject = "SELECT * FROM title ORDER BY added";
    $result_subject = mysql_query($sql_subject);
    while($row_subject = mysql_fetch_array($result_subject))
    {
        $title = $row_subject['title'];

        $all_values .= "Title($title) and Tag($tag) relevancy:". compareStrings($tag, $title) . "%"."<br/>";
    }
}
echo $all_values;
```

Output:

```
Title(Audi is a great car) and Tag(Audi) relevancy:20%
Title(Audi is a great car) and Tag(BMW) relevancy:0%
Title(Audi is a great car) and Tag(Volkswagen) relevancy:0%
Title(Audi is a great car) and Tag(Mercedes Benz) relevancy:0%
```

The question is: how to extract most relevant tag from $all_values and insert into database, because here I am stuck. Or maybe there is a better solution. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: In this instance, it's easy, because while one tag has some relevance, the others have none. So, it's not really a representative example, is it?

Comment: Reality will be more complex. But the point is that i need to extract and insert into db tag with highest percent of relevant.

Comment: Exactly. That point is elegantly ignored by this example.

Comment: Put the stuff into an array, sort it so that you get the tag(s!) with the highest value, and then insert that into the database ... FYI, database queries nested into loops are bad for performance. There is no reason at all here to nest queries in the first place. Read all your tags in one query, the titles in another, put both into arrays. Loop over those arrays afterwards, instead of performing the same database query over and over.

Comment: You must define how to determine relevancy. Simply dividing occurrence with number of words may not be adequate, since most of the time a tag will only occur once in a title.